# Is there a way to get a member by their Discord name?

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I'm coding a Discord bot using Java's JDA package, and am looking for a way to get a member by their Discord name. The name should look something like this: `IPSDSILVA#1849`.

I've looked it up, but the only results that I see are those that include the member's ID in a server, which looks something like this: `1234567890L`.

My code so far is shown below. I have commented on the place where I need help:

```
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.EmbedBuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.guild.GuildMessageReceivedEvent;

public class Commands {
    public void onMessage(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
        String[] args = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split(" ");

        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(Main.prefix + "info")) {
            EmbedBuilder embed = new EmbedBuilder();

            embed.setTitle("Information");
            embed.setDescription("This is a moderation bot. " +
                    "This bot moderates servers that it is in. " +
                    "Enter `?help` for information about the available commands. " +
                    "For help with the bot, suggestions, or more, please contact the creator: IPSDSILVA#1849.");
            embed.setColor(0xff9d00);
            embed.addField("Creator", /* Here, I need to get my profile picture, as the creator. In other words, I need to get my own profile picture, and put it here */, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance, and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just realized how many DMs I could be getting in an instant...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Guild#getMemberAsTag() method. https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Guild.html#getMemberByTag(java.lang.String)